# Boolean Cut Text Through Object

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to cut text through an object but the boolean isnt working no matter what I try. Any ideas from the pros? It comes out all messed up and no hole is ever cut with the text.

Blender file is here: https://file.io/JYHOCQ5CURrN

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your text geometry is not manifold. Create a new text (font → transform → size = $4.3$, geometry → extrude = $5$), then <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *Visual Geometry to Mesh* and use that in your boolean:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU so very much!

Comment: @Tokyov Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't just reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).